# Find the max sum path from bottom left side to top right cell

Tags: java, algorithm, solution

I have to find the maximum sum path in a 2d Array(n,m) given which  has a  value from 0 to 99999. 0 means wall. We have t start from the left bottom side of the array and must reach the right top cell(0,m-1). You can go up/down/right and can visit each cell once. Below is the code without any blocks .My problem is that i cant move from left bottom to right top cell . I also created left array(lest side of the main array) so that i can start from the best value possible .Sorry am  not  good programmer :).

Code

```
 public static int  maxvalue(int [][]field,int[] left)
 {
      for(int i=field.length-1;i>0 && left[i]!=-1;i--)
      {

           System.out.println( "Startpos "+i+" 0");
           int distance =max(i,0,field,0,field.length-1);
           if(distance>maxvalue)
               maxvalue=distance;
      }
     return maxvalue;
 }
 public static int  max(int r, int c,int [][]field ,int destR, int destC)
 {

       if(r>destR|| c>destC)
           return 0;
      if(r==0 && c==field[0].length)
     return  field[r][c];
      int sum1=max(r-1,c,field,destR,destC); // up
      System.out.println(sum1);
      int sum2= max(r+1,c,field,destR,destC);          //down
      int sum3=  max(r,c+1,field,destR,destC);         //right
      return field[r][c]+Math.max(sum1, Math.max(sum2, sum3));
 }
```

Sample

**Input**

0 1 2 **3**

2 0 2 **4**

**3** **3** 0 **3**

**4** **2** **1** **2**

**Output**

25

How to do solve this question? if all the path is blocked then print No Solution.

Comment: Can you share your code so we can know what you have tried and where you're facing problem?

Comment: "You can go up/down/top" What's the difference between up and top? Can you go right? Can you go left?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question, which does not include the required summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, nor a description of the difficulty encountered in solving it.

Comment: I think you may wanna take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Have you first tried to solve it by yourself?

It looks like a bit of work but it is not impossible.

What I would use is 3 int variables : xPosition, yPosition and Sum;

Go on and test the values of xPosition+1, yPosition-1 in priority and then the rest (because you want to reach `xPosition == array.length - 1 && yPosition == 0`.) and if you find a 0, test the other possibilities and exclude the ones you already passed by.

Each time you find a good path, add the value of the cell to your sum.

Reset it to 0 once you're blocked.

Comment: I have a problem with moving from left bottom  to top right of the cell. Initially i started with no blocks.

Comment: Edit your main question and put the code you've already produced.

Answer (score 0):

For every element in the array, you have to find the maximum of the adjacent elements and also check the boundary conditions. I hope this code will help you.

```
public class StackOverFlow {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n = in.nextInt();
    int m = in.nextInt();
    Integer [][] array = new Integer[n][m];
    boolean [][] visited = new boolean[n][m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            array[i][j] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }

    int i = n-1, j =0;
    visited[i][j] = true;
    int sum = array[i][j];
    while(true)
    {

        int max = -1;
        int maxi = 0, maxj = 0;
        if(i-1 >= 0 && i-1<= n-1 && j>=0 && j<= m-1 && array[i-1][j] != null && array[i-1][j]>max && !visited[i-1][j])
        {
            max = array[i-1][j];
            maxi = i-1;
            maxj=j;
        }
        if(i+1 >= 0 && i+1<= n-1 && j>=0 && j<= m-1 &&array[i+1][j] != null  && array[i+1][j]>max && !visited[i+1][j])
        {
            max = array[i+1][j];
            maxi = i+1;
            maxj=j;
        }

        if(i >= 0 && i<= n-1 && j-1>=0 && j-1<= m-1 && array[i][j-1] != null  && array[i][j-1]>max && !visited[i][j-1])
        {
            max = array[i][j-1];
            maxi = i;
            maxj=j-1;
        }

        if(i >= 0 && i<= n-1 && j+1>=0 && j+1<= m-1 && array[i][j+1] != null  && array[i][j+1]>max && !visited[i][j+1])
        {
            max = array[i][j+1];
            maxi = i;
            maxj=j+1;
        }

        i = maxi;
        j = maxj;
        visited[i][j] = true;
        sum += max;

        if(i == 0 && j == m-1)
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);

}
}
```